# Why is the plot title not scaled correctly when scaling the text size with theme(text = element_text())?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a chart that shows two box plots side by side, and I'm trying to scale the text inside the plot, which is giving me issues. I have the problem solved, so I guess now I'm just trying to understand what is going on in the background.

The data can be downloaded [here](https://cidra.sharefile.com/d/sa43d634dadd446c9). (42 MB)

A very basic plot:

```
ggplot(perdiffm, aes(variable, value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Now a plot with proper labels and text size:

```
ggplot(perdiffm, aes(variable, value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') + geom_boxplot() + scale_x_discrete(labels = c('% Difference A', '% Difference B')) + labs(title = "Percent difference between meters", y = '% Difference') + theme(text = element_text(size = rel(5)), axis.title.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Notice the plot title!! I don't understand why that happens, but here is my solution:

```
ggplot(perdiffm, aes(variable, value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar') + geom_boxplot() + scale_x_discrete(labels = c('% Difference A', '% Difference B')) + labs(title = "Percent difference between meters", y = '% Difference') + theme(text = element_text(size = 20), axis.title.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

Basically just changed `text_element(size = rel(5))` to `text_element(size = 20)` (As suggested by Roland)

[image]

So my question is: Why do I have to explicitly code the text size of the title??? Why doesn't `text = element_text(size = rel(5))` not work with the title? (Two questions I guess but they pretty much ask the same thing)

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong (very likely) and how to avoid it in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation `plot.title` inherits from `title` which inherits from `text`. So this seems like a bug.

The canonical way to increase the size of all text is setting the base size in the theme. This preserves the relative text size of all elements.

A plot (without downloading your big dataset, which is unrelated to your question):

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))

p + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Boxplot")
```

[image]

Increasing the base size:

```
p + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Boxplot") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 20) #default is 12
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roland, if I'm not setting the text size to be relative (`size = rel(5)`) I can set the size correctly inside `theme` with `text = element_text(size = 20)`, so no need to add the `base_size` command.